# SDE Integration

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Does anyone know how to get the integration of the SDE below (Assume $\sigma \to 0$)?

> $$\dfrac{\mathrm dS_t}{S_t}=(r_d-r_f)\mathrm dt+\sigma(t, S_t)\mathrm dW_t$$

Thank you in advance!

[Image Link to SDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44W9b.png)

Comment: What is $r_d$ and similar? Any other conditions on $\sigma$?

Comment: Thank you for your response. r_d is the domestic interest rate, which is just a variable. In the SDE above, we assume σ is zero.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume $\sigma = 0$ then we will simply have an ODE : $S_t = S_0\exp((r_d - r_f)t)$. We will need more information on the volatility of the FX rate (i.e. local vol, stochastic vol)?

Thanks.